# JSON to side menu generation in angular5 to n levels

Tags: json, angular, side-menu

I am trying to build a UI where the side menu of the page has to be generated dynamically 
 please find the following json sample

```
{
  "side-menu 1": {
    "id": "",
    "display-name": "",
    "route-id": "",
    "description": "<reference to md file with contents, images, etc>",
    "sub-menu": [
      {
        "id": "",
        "display-name": "",
        "route-id": "",
        "description": "<reference to md file with contents, images, etc>",
        "sub-menu": [
          {
            "id": "",
            "display-name": "",
            "route-id": "",
            "description": "<reference to md file with contents, images, etc>"
          },

          {
            "id": "",
            "display-name": "",
            "route-id": "",
            "description": "<reference to md file with contents, images, etc>"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "",
        "display-name": "",
        "route-id": "",
        "description": "<reference to md file with contents, images, etc>"
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

i have tried with "ng-material-multilevel-menu" and 2 days  but it has some dependency issue please let me know which plugin or the approach i can use to achieve this

Please point some reference example sample in angular 6 to do get this done

Comment: this is a sample for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadcrumb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic side navigation menu&Submenu in ionic2/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257237/how-to-create-dynamic-side-navigation-menusubmenu-in-ionic2-3)

Comment: i am able see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadcrumb can u please point to side nested menu sample

Comment: @ Hien Nguyen  same approach but please point me to nested side menu sample

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. If yes and for new viewers, then I have created a plugin for Angular which creates a Multilevel menu. Now you can convert this multilevel menu to Accordion as well, for example, Check [this example](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/pages/layout-variations/demo-three).

Here is a [NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and [Github Link](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), the documentation is very sweet and simple.

Just in case, if you wanna see more examples, I have a [demo](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/) for you and this is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu-demo) of the demo.

If something doesn't work for you, and you still wanna use this plugin, then [create an issue](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues) here I'll help you out.

P.S. it works in IE11 as well.

Thanks